# $P(\max(x_1,...,x_k) < \min(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n))$, where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are random numbers in range [0,1]

Tags: probability

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ uniformly distributed, independent, random numbers in the range $[0,1]$.

Let $1\leq k< n$.

What is $$P(\max(x_1,...,x_k) \lt \min(x_{k+1},...,x_n))$$, as a function of $k$ and $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we reorder the variables by value, $y_1<\ldots<y_n$.

Then, $P(\max(x_1,\ldots,x_k)<\min(x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n))=P(\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}=\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\})$.

There are ${n \choose k}$ subsets of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of size $k$, each of which has the same probability of being $\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\}$.

Hence the probability that $\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\}=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ is ${n \choose k}^{-1}$.

Comment: Why $P(\max(x_1,\ldots,x_k)<\min(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n))=P(\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}=\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\})$?

Comment: It is rather any permutation of $\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}=\{y_1,\dots,y_k\}$...?

Comment: @RobertW. all this is saying is that the probability that the first k elements are smaller than all the other elements is the same as the probability that when sorted, the first k elements appear in the first k positions. Hope it makes sense in words. It is trivial to prove by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=n-k$, $X_{(k)}=\max(x_1,...,x_k)$, and $Y_{(1)}=\min(x_{k+1},...,x_n)$. Then since $X_{(k)}\sim \text{Beta}(k, 1)$ and $Y_{(1)}\sim\text{Beta}(1, m)$

$$P\{X_{(k)}<Y_{(1)}\}=\mathbb{E}[P\{X_{(k)} \lt Y_{(1)}|Y_{(1)}\}]$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{x^{k-1}(1-x)^0}{\beta(k,1)}\frac{y^0(1-y)^{m-1}}{\beta(1,m)}dxdy=m\cdot \beta(m,k+1)=\left[\binom{n}{k}\right]^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Choosing easier to use names for variables:

> Given two finite sequences, $x$ and $y$, with each element of each sequence uniformly distributed from $0$ to $1$, what is the probability
>
> $$P = \text{Prob}(\max x < \min y)$$

(For this answer I will use the [Kronecker delta operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) as $\text{KR}[~\dots~]$).

Writing out the problem algebraically:

$$P = \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{x_2 = 0}^1 ~ \dots ~\int_{y_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_2 = 0}^1 ~ \dots ~ {\rm KR}[ \max x < \min y ] ~{\rm d}y~{\rm d}x$$

First step, to isolate the "largest" value of $x$ and the "smallest" value of $y$.  The largest value of $x$ will be $x_1$ one out of $|x|$ times, (similarly the smallest value of $y$ will be $y_1$ one out of $|y|$ times,)

$$\begin{align}
%
P &= \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{x_2 = 0}^1 ~ \dots ~\int_{y_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_2 = 0}^1 ~ \dots ~ {\rm KR}[ \max x < \min y ] ~{\rm d}y~{\rm d}x
%
\\ &= |x|~\int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{x_2 = 0}^{x_1} ~ \int_{x_3 = 0}^{x_1} 
         ~ \dots ~
         \int_{y_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_2 = 0}^{1} ~ \int_{y_3 = 0}^{1} ~ \dots ~ {\rm KR}[ \max x < \min y ] ~{\rm d}y~{\rm d}x
%
\\ &= |x|~|y|~ \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{x_2 = 0}^{x_1} ~ \int_{x_3 = 0}^{x_1} 
               ~ \dots ~
               \int_{y_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_2 = y_1}^{1} ~ \int_{y_2 = y_1}^{1} ~ \dots ~ {\rm KR}[ \max x < \min y ] ~{\rm d}y~{\rm d}x
%
\\ &= |x|~|y|~\int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{x_2 = 0}^{x_1} ~ \int_{x_3 = 0}^{x_1} 
              ~ \dots ~
              \int_{y_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_2 = y_1}^{1} ~ \int_{y_3 = y_1}^{1} ~ \dots ~ {\rm KR}[ x_1 < y_1 ] ~{\rm d}y~{\rm d}x
%
\end{align}$$

...which has now made $x_1$ and $y_1$ the largest and smallest variables (respectively) along the integration.

Now change the order of integration to make use of this:

$$\begin{align}
%
P &= |x| ~ |y| ~ \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_1 = 0}^1~ {\rm KR}[ x_1 < y_1 ] ~
                 \int_{x_2 = 0}^{x_1} ~ \int_{x_3 = 0}^{x_1} 
                 ~ \dots ~
                 ~ \int_{y_2 = y_1}^{1} ~ \int_{y_3 = y_1}^{1} ~\dots ~ 1 ~{\rm d}{y}~{\rm d}{x}
%
\\  &= |x| ~ |y| ~ \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_1 = 0}^1~ {\rm KR}[ x_1 < y_1 ] ~
                   x_1{}^{|x| - 1} (1 - y_1)^{|y| - 1}
                   ~{\rm d}y_1 ~{\rm d}x_1
%
\end{align}$$

...where the second step just comes as the result of integrating a multidimensional rectangular prism, which is just multiplying.  Now the Kronecker can be merged into the domain of integration:

$$\begin{align}
%
    &= |x| ~ |y| ~ \int_{x_1 = 0}^1 ~ \int_{y_1 = x_1}^1~ 
                   x_1^{|x| - 1} (1 - y_1)^{|y| - 1}
                   ~{\rm d}y_1 ~{\rm d}x_1
%
\\  &= \frac{ |x| ~ |y| ~ \beta(|x|, |y|) }{|x| + |y|}
%
\\  &= \frac{ |x| ~ |y| ~ (|x| - 1)!~(|y| - 1)! } { (|x| + |y| - 1)! (|x| + |y|)}
%
\\  &= \frac{ |x|!~|y|! } { (|x| + |y|)! }
%
\\  &= {|x| + |y| \choose |x|}^{-1} = {|x| + |y| \choose |y|}^{-1}
%
\end{align}$$

Using the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) for integration.  Obviously, the chances are very low for any non very small values of $|x|$ and $|y|$, for example, given $|x| = 4$ and $|y| = 3$ gives:

$$P(4, 3) = \frac{1}{35}$$

For larger values, consider $|x| = 10$ and $|y| = 15$:

$$P(10, 15) = \frac{1}{3,268,760}$$